# Cannot get no. of photos in a Facebook Album

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am listing the photo albums in my fb account using facebook-c#-sdk 5.0.25

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        fb.AccessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;

        IDictionary<string, object> albums = fb.Get("me/albums") as IDictionary<string, object>;

        dynamic albumList = albums["data"];

        foreach (dynamic albumInfo in albumList)
        {
            strAlbid = albumInfo.id;
            strAlbName = albumInfo.name;
            strAlbDesc = albumInfo.description;
            strAlbCnt = albumInfo.count;
            strAlbInfo = albumInfo.link;
        }
```

But I cannot get no. of photos in an album because albumInfo.count is not returning any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from the snippet you've posted, but it appears as though you are attempting to cast the Count as a string (from the variable name strAlbCnt).

Count is a JSON integer - the [official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) claims it is a string, but that is, like many other things on the documentation, not accurate.  Check [this public example of an album](https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071791729) to see what I mean:

```
"name": "Happy Lunar New Year 2011",
"link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=324257&id=20531316728",
"cover_photo": "10150146072661729",
"count": 79,
"type": "normal",
```

Note that cover_photo is a string despite being numeric, but Count doesn't have the quotes around it, making it a JSON integer.

I can't say for sure this is the cause of your problem, but I have had similar problems coming from dynamic objects before so it's something I instantly suspect.

Comment: FWIW, I believe count is typed as a long, not an int.

Comment: I use **dynamic albums = app.Get("me/albums");** How can I get for public album _www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=10150146071791729&id=20531316728&aid=324257_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same issue you were encountering, but I had something akin to this:

```
int albumCount == Data.count;
```

This would throw a conversion exception because the count field is actually long.  So this worked:

```
long albumCount == Data.count;
```