# Trying to get my facebook album ids

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched and searched the forums without any help. I know this is trivial and I have just missed something. Albums keeps coming back with nothing in it. I have verified that my accessToken is valid.

```
            string folderName = string.Empty;

        var accessToken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        dynamic albums = client.Get("/me/albums");

        foreach (dynamic album in albums)
        {
            folderName = album.name;

            //dynamic albumsPhotos = client.Get("me/" + album.id + "/photos");

            //foreach (dynamic photo in albumsPhotos)
            //{

            //}
        }
```

Comment: I looked through these forums and found lots of examples of people getting their albums and photos. For some reason though, I can't get any of my albums. Wasn't sure if it was something I was missing or I was doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

To read an Album you need:

- Any valid access token if it is public and belongs to a Page
- The user_photos permission if it belongs to a User
- The friend_photos permission if it belongs to a User's friend

The other thing to check is the dynamic object, see here: [Cannot get no. of photos in a Facebook Album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992104/cannot-get-no-of-photos-in-a-facebook-album)

Comment: I use dynamic albums = app.Get("me/albums"); How can I get for public album (not me) www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=10150146071791729&id=20531316728&aid=324257 ?